# Why is this for loop not working as expected?

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I have made a for loop which is not working as expected. Please see the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
    s = s + "k";
    for (int ii = 0; ii < result.get(0).size(); ii++) {
        s = s + "\n";
        s = s + result.get(i).get(ii)[0];
    }
}
```

`result.get(i).get(ii)[0]` should output a String, which is outputted successfully, but the problem is that the String `s` should contain a *"k"* every time before adding the three strings, so it should be like:

```
kString1

String2

String3

kString1

String2

String3
```

I am only getting a *"k"* one time before the string. I know that the value of `i` is updating because the `result.get(i)` is giving results with the updated `i`.

Explaining `result.get(i).get(ii)[0]`:

`s` is a String, result is an `ArrayList< ArrayList< String[]>>` which means that it contains `ArrayList< String[]>` objects and each object of `ArrayList< String[]> is a String array.

EDIT: I am now adding the output I am getting:

```
k

United King

["bakery","store","food","establishment"]

0

Oven Fresh Bakery

["bakery","store","food","establishment"]

1

5 Star CNG Pump Station

["gas_station","establishment"]

2
```

There should be a "k" right after 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: What is `s` ? Which type I mean.

Comment: Don't use `string = string + additionalValue`. You should use `StringBuilder` and its `append` method to build strings.

Comment: Also to be able to help you we will need *short* but *complete* example which will let us actually reproduce your problem. Also informations about *actual* and *expected* output would be helpful.

Comment: You're missing essential parts of the code, aka I don't think we can help you at all.

Comment: @Kabulan0lak s is a String. @ Pshemo I have edited my post

Comment: I wanted to know the type of result, not s sorry. But @Elliot Frisch lightened me

Answer (score 2):

Your nested loop condition appears to be incorrect,

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < result.get(0).size(); ii++) {
```

should be

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < result.get(i).size(); ii++) {
```

**Edit** (Based on your comments and edit, next time - please include a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/) for better help faster)

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
ArrayList<String[]> t = new ArrayList<String[]>();
t.add(new String[] { "String1" });
t.add(new String[] { "String2" });
t.add(new String[] { "String3" });

result.add(t);
result.add(t);

for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
    for (int ii = 0; ii < result.get(i).size(); ii++) {
        if (i != 0 || ii != 0) {
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        if (ii == 0) {
            sb.append("k");
        }
        sb.append(result.get(i).get(ii)[0]);
    }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output is

```
kString1
String2
String3
kString1
String2
String3
```

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering what he wanted with the zero index, but I couldn't figure it out. Nice catch.

Comment: I doesn't solve the problem, I have used 0 because I know that the size of every object is same.

Comment: @Usman what problem? `String 3k` is getting the `k` twice. What output do you expect? Did you want `s = s + "\nk";` So that it's on a newline? Also, use a StringBuilder.

Comment: the problem is that I don't get String 3k, I just get a newline character followed by String1,2,3 of next object(i) again. I need it like this: k > 3 strings > k > 3 Strings > k....

Comment: @Usman Edited based on your comments / edits.

Comment: Thanks, your code works, so did my code. I found out that the problem was somewhere else in my code which made the value of result.get(0).size() 21 instead of 3. Apparently, the list was messed up and containing all values in each ArrayList object, and k was printing, but it was too far down that I could not catch it.